# How to convert Future List instance to List String in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am saving strings list in shared procedure and fetching that like below

```
Future<List<String>> getList() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getStringList("key");
}
```

Issue is that I need to send that list to server but facing issue as I need to convert that future list to simple List

How can I do that? or is there any other way as I need to send list of ids save by user to server.

Comment: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: @pskink can you please explain it please . Thank you :)

Comment: did you find any approach? I'm facing the exact problem ...

Answer (score 5):

When you mark a function as **async** it will **return a future**.

If you dont **wait** for the future you will get '**Future instance**' this means your future(data) is not available yet.

If you want to **wait** for the future(data) to be resolved you need to use the **await** keyword.

So in your case you can create a `List<String> myList;` then create a function to wait for the future and assign the data to the previous List.

```
List<String> myList;
void getStringList() async {
var tempList = await getList();
// Or use setState to assign the tempList to myList
myList = tempList;
}
```

Or use **Then**:

```
getList().then(List<String> myList {
// TODO: Send myList to server.
});
```

Hope this helpe!!

Answer (score 1):

When you work with async data you should "wait" while data will not completely loaded. You can use `await` word in async methods like that:

```
foo() async {
  final Future<List<dynamic>> futureList = fetchSomeFutureList();
  final list = await futureList;
}
```

or use Future's `then()` method to delegate some work. 
You also can wait for futures in widget tree using `FutureBuilder`.
Check [Dart Docs](http://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) page for see details.